# Rellenar vector con 1000000 de numeros al azar

Tags: java, array, complejidad

Estoy en un curso de estructura da datos enfocado en Java y tengo la tarea de rellenar un "vector" con numeros del 1 al 1000000 aleatorios sin que se repitan. La tarea quiere que se haga en maximo 2 segundos, dijo que usaramos la clase Collection pero no le hallo ya que dijo que investigaramos y he tratado de usar varios de los tipos de colecciones de la misma clase pero no me sale :c
Algun consejo?
Aqui esta mi progreso

```
int n=10;
int [] vec=new int[n];
HashSet<Integer> matrix=new HashSet();

void Rellenar()
{ 
    int i=0;
    int x=n;
    int m;
    //vec[i]=(int)(Math.random()*x);
    matrix.add((int)(Math.random()*x+1));
    for(i=1; i<=n; i++)
    {
        matrix.add((int)(Math.random()*x+1));
        for(int j=0; j<i; j++)
        {
            if(matrix.get(i)==matrix.get(j))
            {
                i--;
            }
        }
    }

}

void Mostrar()
{
    Iterator<Integer> it=matrix.iterator();
    while(it.hasNext())
    {
        System.out.println(it.next()+"\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Porque no compartes el código que tienes hasta el momento?

Comment: Consejos: no intentes generar aleatoriamente los números: genera los números del uno al millon y luego *mézclalos*, como si fuera una baraja. Te evitas las colisiones (números repetidos)

Answer (score 2):

No te han pedido que usaras Collection, sino Collections. Lo más sencillo es algo así:

```
ArrayList<Integer> al = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
    al.add(i, i);
}
Collections.shuffle(al);
```

Ahora los elementos del ArrayList están mezclados en orden aleatorio. Y tarda muy poco.

Pero le doy la razón a @Capt.Teach - no deberíamos de dar soluciones si no se ha mostrado ningún interés en hacer el trabajo

Comment: Pienso que es una buena solución ya que la complejidad de la operación shuffle es O(n). Me pregunto si existe una solución mejor, algo como O(logn).

Comment: Interesante pero no creo que se pueda. Para ser la mezcla eficiente debemos mover cada elemento de la lista, así que tenemos una complejidad de O(n). Esto - https://www.quora.com/Are-there-any-better-shuffling-algorithms-than-Fisher%E2%80%93Yates-shuffle es una reflexion interesante (la segunda respuesta) sobre aleatoriedad y mezcla paralela.

Answer (score 0):

No estoy seguro de entender el problema, pero parece bastante evidente que necesitas usar un [`HashSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html). Lo bueno del `HashSet` es que no puedes tener valores duplicados. Si intentas meter uno que ya está, no funcionará, entonces no tienes que comprobar si ya existe algo en él antes de insertarlo.

No tengo claro si te pide que insertes 1.000.000 de números, o números del 1 al 1.000.000, o ambos (en cuyo caso, tendrás todos los números, así que da igual si es aleatorio o no).

Pero bueno, te dejo el código para usar un `HashSet` e insertar 1.000.000 de números aleatorios entre el 1 y el 1.000.000 (es decir, todos). Y desde ahí podrás adaptar el programa a tus necesidades.

```java
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Set<Integer> listaNumeros = new HashSet<Integer>();

        while(listaNumeros.size() < 1000000) {
            int randomNum = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1, 1000000 + 1);

            listaNumeros.add(randomNum);
        }

        System.out.println(listaNumeros.size());
    }
}
```

Comment: Hay un criterio de **que la tarea quiere que se haga en máximo 2 segundos** y este código a mi siempre se me ejecuta en mas de 2s en un equipo *i5-4460 / 3.2GHz / 16GB RAM*. Suponemos que en un 386 tardaría bastante más así que el criterio de los 2 segundos es poco consistente.

Comment: Porque respondes a preguntas de quiero x / hacedme y ?? El usuario no ha aportado ni la mas mínima linea de código de lo que ha intentado

Comment: @EvgeniEnchev a mi me va en menos de 2 segundos. ¿Qué propondrías tú entonces? Igualmente, sigo sin entender para qué generar 1.000.000 de números aleatorios distintos entre el 1 y 1.000.000, para eso, insertas todos en el `HashSet` y ya, igualmente el orden no se va a mantener...

Comment: Si se analiza la complejidad de la operación del ejemplo  listaNumeros.add(randomNum) correspondiente al HashSet esta es O(1)  pero el problema se encuentra en el aumento del número de colisiones cuando la lista de listaNumeros está cada vez más llena. Entonces la complejidad de añadir un número empeora, no es O(1). Tal vez sea la respuesta a los 2 segundos.